# How to find C++ symbol definition by name in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I know I can go to the definition of a symbol in visual studio by double clicking on it in a source windows and then hitting F12 "Go to definition", but how can I go to the definition of a symbol if its name isn't being displayed in the current source window. The best I've been able to do is search for the symbol name in the find and replace dialog, and then hit F12 on one of the results, but there has to be some way to search definitions by name, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Object Browser.  You can bring it up by going to the View menu and choosing Object Browser.  Make sure the "Browse:" field is set to "My Solution", and then type the name of the symbol into the search box and click the magnifying glass icon.

Comment: I'm afraid that was the first thing I tried. Doesn't work :(